Make a live plotter with pyqtgraph with clear the plott bevor with a black distance to the plott bevor
I want to plott live data with the pyqtgraph. This is a minimal code sample:

from random import randint

import pyqtgraph as pg
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Temperature vs time dynamic plot
        self.plot_graph = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.plot_graph)
        self.plot_graph.setBackground("w")
        pen = pg.mkPen(color=(255, 0, 0))
        self.plot_graph.setTitle("Temperature vs Time", color="b", size="20pt")
        styles = {"color": "red", "font-size": "18px"}
        self.plot_graph.setLabel("left", "Temperature (°C)", **styles)
        self.plot_graph.setLabel("bottom", "Time (min)", **styles)
        self.plot_graph.addLegend()
        self.plot_graph.showGrid(x=True, y=True)
        self.plot_graph.setYRange(20, 40)
        self.time = list(range(10))
        self.temperature = [randint(20, 40) for _ in range(10)]
        # Get a line reference
        self.line = self.plot_graph.plot(
            self.time,
            self.temperature,
            name="Temperature Sensor",
            pen=pen,
            symbol="+",
            symbolSize=15,
            symbolBrush="b",
        )
        # Add a timer to simulate new temperature measurements
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(300)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_plot)
        self.timer.start()

    def update_plot(self):
        self.time = self.time[1:]
        self.time.append(self.time[-1] + 1)
        self.temperature = self.temperature[1:]
        self.temperature.append(randint(20, 40))
        self.line.setData(self.time, self.temperature)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
main = MainWindow()
main.show()
app.exec()

But i want to adjust this solution to load a run of data in an puffer and then i want to plott the data in the "consumer_buffer". The data in the consumer_buffer are all data i can plott in one run, after the run the skript will load again the data vor 1 plott in the consumer_buffer an plott them, but the plott should began on the left side an with some black distance to the plott bevor, like this:

I have tried some versions from the code above and searche vor a tutorial, but i don't find a solution, maybe someone can help? My main problem is: how i get the black distance?
